# Should we use PropTypes for Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

I have a very simple question for which I have not found any satisfying answer on web so far.
Currently I am adding PropTypes in a react application. So, it has redux implemented and I was wondering if I should type check the state coming from redux.

I have a parent component lets say Component1, which renders three different components - something like this -

```
const Component1 = (props) => {
 return (
  <>
    <Component2 someProps={...} />
    <Component3 someProps={...} />
    <Component4 someProps={...} />
  </>
 )
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { details: state.details }; //should I use proptypes to check type of details? //
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component1);
```

Does it make sense to type check the state coming from redux here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not seen that done, you could I suppose use defaults parameters for state values . Or use TypesScript see link https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. Because it's props. And no matter where they are from

```
const Component1 = (props) => {
 return (
  <>
    <Component2 someProps={...} />
    <Component3 someProps={...} />
    <Component4 someProps={...} />
  </>
 )
}

Component1.propTypes = {
  details: PropTypes.shape({
    name: string,
    age: number
  })
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { details: state.details }; //should I use proptypes to check type of details? //
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component1);
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I didn't knew you can use shape to give typing to keys of an object. Thanks